# VS2010: Set what directory an executable looks for files in

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have set my project to output my .exe file into a specific directory, and if I run this compiled executable outside of Visual Studio, it can find and use the files around it using `cstdio`.  However, if I run it within Visual Studio, those files are suddenly gone, as if it's in the wrong directory.

What is causing this, and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will run the program that's "over there" in its own project folder, so the program's working directory, where it creates and looks for files etc..., will be the project directory and not where the executable is stored.

You can do this yourself. Open a command prompt and type the full path to the executable. It will run, write, and look for files in the prompt's current folder.

Do not use `argv[0]`. this will give you the command line, and might not include the actual location of the executable.

If you want to keep your files with the executable no matter where the program is run from, [GetModuleFileName will tell you where the executable is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx). You can then strip off the executable to get the path and concatenate that with the names of other files you want to stay in the same folder as, or relative to, the executable. With this approach you can run the program from anywhere, including Visual Studio.

If you want to know where the executable is being run from and make your own way, [use _getcwd.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx)

If all you care about is Visual Studio, navigate to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging and set the Working Directory to the target directory

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that what you **really** want to do is to copy the executable elsewhere **after** the build. That way you don't have to have anything special in the executable that is only for debugging (development). You can have Visual Studio do the copy for you **automatically** using a Custom Build Step. The build should create the executable in the same project directory that it normally does, then the copy will be done after that (like a mini deployment).

In the project's properties:

- Select "Build Events" | "Post-Build Step"
- Enter a post build event command to do the copy, for example:

  copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "G:\Temporary"

Where "G:\Temporary" is wherever you want the file to be copied to.

Be mindful of the configuration. You can choose to create the Custom Build Step for both debug and release configurations, but then the executable will be copied to the same place for both configurations. You probably will want a different copy command for each configuration.

While in the property page for entering the Custom Build Step, you can click the down-arrow and select "Edit..." (inside the less than and greater than symbols) to get help creating the command. While doing that, click on "Macros>>" to see the big list of available macros.